# Each time I send INSERT query add + 1 to a mysql database's field. INSERT (NOT UPDATE)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert, field

This is my table named **galleries**:
[Click here to see a table named galleries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oqGj.jpg)
As you can see there are fields named: id, path and gallery_id.
I wrote a script, which uploads multiple images after an insert query:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['image']['name']); $i++)
{
    $path = 'sent_images/'.$_FILES['image']['name'][$i];
    $gallery_id = '1';

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');

    $q = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO galleries (path, gallery_id) VALUES (?, ?)');
    $q->bind_param('si', $path, $gallery_id);
    $q->execute();

    if($q->affected_rows > 0)
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i], $path);
    }
}
```

The script works fine. Let me show, what do I want the script to do:

1. I upload for an example 3 images for the first time:
   The field "gallery_id" looks like:

> ```
> id | patch       | gallery_id 
> ---------------------------------
> 1  | some patch  |   1
> 2  | some patch  |   1
> 3  | some patch  |   1
> ```

2. I upload for an example 5 images for the second time:
   The field "gallery_id" looks like:

> ```
> id | patch       | gallery_id 
> ---------------------------------
> 1  | some patch  |   1
> 2  | some patch  |   1
> 3  | some patch  |   1
> 4  | some patch  |   2
> 5  | some patch  |   2
> 6  | some patch  |   2
> 7  | some patch  |   2
> 8  | some patch  |   2
> ```
>
> etc.

I found that something like:

```
INSERT INTO galleries (path, gallery_id) VALUES (?, ?) SELECT max(gallery_id) + 1 FROM galleries
```

would help, but I do not know, how to use it in the script above.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Our forum friend **Vigneswaran S** helped me to find the solution. To make the code work all we have to do is just:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'gracom');

$q = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT MAX(gallery_id) FROM galleries');
$q->execute();
$q->bind_result($gallery_id);
$q->store_result();

while($q->fetch())
{
    $gallery_id = $gallery_id + 1;

    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['image']['name']); $i++)
    {
        $path = 'sent_images/'.$_FILES['image']['name'][$i];

        $q = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO galleries (path, gallery_id) VALUES (?, ?)');
        $q->bind_param('si', $path, $gallery_id);
        $q->execute();

        if($q->affected_rows > 0)
        {
            echo 'Done!';
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i], $path);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank You for the help, guys.

Comment: Sorry, your post is not clear. The description does not match the sample image you link to. All the gallery_ids in the example have a single digit but in the text you have multiple digits. What exactly is your goal for the gallery_id field?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My goal is:
For the first time I upload some images there are inserted some rows at which all fields "gallery_id" have number "1".
When I upload some images twice, then there are inserted some rows, which all fields of new inserted "gallery_id" have number "2".
Everytime I insert new rows to table, the field "gallery_id" is higher about +1 than the last time inserted fields.

Comment: can u add your expected output. have you used auto increment for your id?

Comment: Hello. Ofcourse, I use auto_increment for an "id" field and it works. I edited the topic, can you refresh the page and see what do I want to do? thanks. Should be cleared now.

Comment: what is wrong with your code ? what do u want to happen?your gallery_id  should always 1 right

Comment: I want to add + 1 to every new field named "gallery_id" like on the examples I've just wrote above. Normally the script add only 1 to each "gallery_id". I want to add + 1 to new rows, which were inserted. But not to every rows, only to new inserted rows (uploaded images). I tried something like this: "INSERT INTO galleries (path, gallery_id) VALUES (?, ?) SELECT max(gallery_id) + 1 FROM galleries" but it doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried the answer given below

Comment: Yes, I have tried and it doesn't work. Look at this: imgur.com/E8fl444

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'gracom');
$gallery_id = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT MAX(gallery_id) FROM galleries'); // returns max value
$gallery_id->execute();
$gallery_id = $gallery_id + 1; // retrieve the value and increment 

for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['image']['name']); $i++)
{
  $path = 'sent_images/'.$_FILES['image']['name'][$i];

  $q = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO galleries (path, gallery_id) VALUES (?, ?)');
  $q->bind_param('si', $path, $gallery_id);
  $q->execute();

  if($q->affected_rows > 0)
  {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i], $path);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer, but it still doesnt work. The "galery_id" of every new inserted row is improved by 1. So it looks like:
id | patch       | gallery_id 
---------------------------------
1  | some patch  |   1
2  | some patch  |   1
3  | some patch  |   1

4  | some patch  |   2
5  | some patch  |   3
6  | some patch  |   4
7  | some patch  |   5
8  | some patch  |   6
But really thanks, man, for trying to resolve the problem.

Comment: @WojciechGlapa: your expected output should be a increment of last inserted $gallery_id value ?am i right

Comment: Hey, there! I've just resolved the problem. Thank you so much! Without You it could takes years! =) I will add the solution in the main topic. Just a second.

Comment: @WojciechGlapa: feeling happy to solved your problem :).

Answer (score 0):

Look up the mysql documentation for AUTO_INCREMENT. You can define the column to automatically increment each time a record is inserted.